# Что в коде противоречит парадигме функционального программирования?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функциональное-программирование

На вход подаются две последовательности (a₁,…,an) и (b₁,…,bn) из 0 и 1.

Вычислите последовательность из (c₁,…,cn), где каждая cᵢ=xor(aᵢ,bᵢ).

```
import sys


def xor(a, b):
    return ((not a) * b) + (a * (not b))


print(
    *map(
        xor,
        map(
            int,
            sys.stdin.readline().split()
        ),
        map(
            int,
            sys.stdin.readline().split()
        )
    )
)
```

проверочная система отвечает: Precompile check failed: not functional enough

Comment: Может она ждёт лямбду вместо объявления функции?

Comment: это нужно спросить у авторов системы, что эта ошибка означает.

Comment: как по мне, так вполне себе функционально получилось... Может проверочная система ожидает однострочное (one-liner) выражение?

Comment: Возможно, дело в def. Он имеет побочный эффект. Больше ничего примечательного не вижу. Да и этот def мелочь, если он далее нигде не переопределяется.

Comment: Спасибо, D-side, видимо стояла проверка на наличие def

Comment: теоретически, ещё и print - "недостаточно функционален" =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помогла замена Функции

```
def xor(a, b):
    return ((not a) * b) + (a * (not b))
```

на `lambda`

```
lambda a, b: ((not a) * b) + (a * (not b))
```

Comment: наличие именованных функций не противоречит функциональному программированию.